# komische Bedeutung von "erst"

Tags: modal-particle

> Jetzt tue ich es **erst** recht!
>
> Wie muss es dort **erst** aussehen!

Diese zwei Beispiele stammen aus dem [DWDS.de](https://www.dwds.de/wb/erst#d-1-1-1) und leider bin ich nicht in der Lage, sie völlig zu verstehen. Auf DWDS steht, dass *»erst«* eine Hervorhebung, Steigerung bezeichnet. Das vollziehe ich nicht. Was soll das bedeuten?

Ich bitte euch um Hilfe. Englisch wäre auch hilfreich.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Das Wort *»erst«* gibt es als Adverb:

> Du must dir **erst** die Schuhe ausziehen.
> Ich habe dich **erst** erkannt, als du den Mantel ausgezogen hast.
> Er wird **erst** morgen hier sein.
> Es ist **erst** 7 Uhr!

> You have to take off your shoes **first.**
> I didn't recognize you **until** you took off your coat.
> He won't be here **until** tomorrow.
> It's **only** 7 o'clock!

Es gibt aber auch ein Homonym, das eine Modalpartikel ist. Dieses Wort hat eine völlig andere Bedeutung. Es bedeutet eine starke Steigerung der Aussage. Modalpartikel werden vor allem im gesprochenen Deutsch sehr häufig verwendet, aber sie existieren in vielen Sprachen entweder gar nicht oder werden nur sehr selten eingesetzt. Englisch ist eine Sprache, sie fast gar keine Modalpartikel verwendet. Nachdem Modalpartikel die eigentliche Bedeutung des Satzes nicht verändern, sondern nur ein Gefühl hinzufügen oder ein Gefühl, das ohnehin ausgedrückt wird verstärken, lassen sie sich nur schwer ins Englische übersetzten. Am häufigsten wird das Problem dadurch gelöst, dass man Modalpartikel beim Übersetzten einfach ignoriert.

> Du hältst meinen Onkel für verrückt? Da solltest du **erst** meinen Vater sehen! Der ist noch viel verrückter.
> You think my uncle is crazy? You should see my father! He's even crazier. (The word *erst* is omitted during translation.)

> Wie muss es dort *erst* aussehen!
> What must it look like there! (The word *erst* is omitted during translation.)

Sehr häufig wird diese Partikel mit dem Wort *»recht«* zu *»erst recht«* verbunden. Diese beiden Wörter drücken gemeinsam Trotz aus und bedeuten fast dasselbe wie *»trotzdem«* oder *»aus Trotz«*:

> Wenn die mir das verbieten wollen, mache ich das **erst recht.**
> If they want to forbid me to do that, I'll do it **all the more.**

> Jetzt tue ich es **erst recht!** = Jetzt tue ich es **aus Trotz!**
> Now I do it **more than ever!** = Now I do it **out of defiance!**

The English translation *»out of defiance* matches better to the meaning of *»erst recht«* because *»more than ever«* implies that you did it less before, but *»erst recht«* does not contain this implication. You could have done it not at all before, or with the same intensity.

Answer (score 1):

Das erste Beispiel enthält die Partikelkombination *erst recht*, die man gesondert betrachten muss. Die Bedeutung ist *aus Trotz; gerade deshalb, weil jemand anders dagegen ist*.

In dem zweiten Beispiel steht das Partikel *erst* tatsächlich allein. Die Bedeutung ist in diesem Beispiel *So schlimm, ich mag es mir gar nicht vorstellen.* Eine schwächere Alternative dazu ist *bloß*, eine noch verstärkte Alternative ist *überhaupt erst*.

Leider kann man bei den Modalpartikeln den Sinn immer nur aus dem Zusammenhang verstehen. Die ungefähre Bedeutung des Modalpartikels *erst* ist *meine Erwartung wird übertroffen.*

Comment: *Erst recht* lässt sich ganz gut mit *nevertheless* übersetzen.

Comment: @guidot: *»nevertheless«* würde ich mit *»dennoch«* oder *»ohnehin«* übersetzen. Ich nehme im Wort *»nevertheless«* keinen Trotz, keinen Protest und keine Auflehnung wahr. Trotz, Protest und Auflehnung sind aber grundlegende Bestandteile von *»erst recht«.* Wenn eine Handlung erst dadurch zustande kommt, dass man sie verbietet, eignet sich *»erst recht«* ganz hervorragend, um das zu beschrieben, aber das würde ich dann niemals mit *»nevertheless«* übersetzen. ...

Comment: ... Ein Beispiel: *»Der Direktor verbot allen Mädchen der Schule das Tragen von Miniröcken. Daraufhin kauften sich einige Mädchen solche Röcke und trugen sie **erst recht.**«* - *»... and wore them nevertheless«* passt da nicht, denn gemeint ist *»aus Trotz«* also *»... and wore them out of defiance«* oder *»... and wore them in protest«*